# EclipseLink MOXy with spring MVC for RESTful services not working for JSON

Tags: java, eclipselink, weblogic-10.x, moxy

Here is the situation.

When I use [**EclipseLink MOXy**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) with Spring 3 MVC to generate JSON output it throws following exception when I try to set the json media type  with following statement.

**marshaller.setProperty(JAXBContextProperties.MEDIA_TYPE, "application/json");**

```
javax.xml.bind.PropertyException: name: eclipselink.media-type value: application/json
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBMarshaller.setProperty(JAXBMarshaller.java:520)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:176)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:436)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:424)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:790)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:669)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:574)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
```

I am using JAXBviews too to generate xml output for other services in the application. Here is the beans declaration in application-context.xml for the same.

```
<bean id="jaxbMarshaller"    class="com.abc.restws.marshallers.ClasspathScanningJaxb2Marshaller">
    <property name="basePackages" ref="jaxbBasePackages" />
</bean> 


    <bean id="jaxbMarshallingView" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.xml.MarshallingView">
        <property name="marshaller" ref="jaxbMarshaller"/>
    </bean> 
    <bean id="jaxbJsonMarshallingView" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.xml.MarshallingView">
        <property name="contentType" value="application/json"/>
        <property name="marshaller" ref="jaxbJsonMarshaller"/>
    </bean>
```

What's the reason for this error? How can i fix this error? XML output is generated fine but for JSON it throws this exception. You can see in the exception details it's using correct JAXBMarshaller class too to set the json media type.  Please advice.

**"org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBMarshaller.setProperty(JAXBMarshaller.java:520)"**

Answer (score 1):

**Note:**  I'm the [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) lead and a member of the [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) expert group.

JSON binding was added to EclipseLink in version 2.4, and you are using WebLogic 10.3.4 (11g) which contains EclipseLink 2.1.2.  The recommended solution to this problem is to create a shared library in WebLogic for the newer release of EclipseLink.

**CREATE THE SHARED LIBRARY**

WebLogic has the concept of [shared libraries](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17904_01/web.1111/e13706/libraries.htm#i1064656).  These are deployed as an EAR.  Below is what the EAR will look like for creating a shared library for EclipseLink 2.4.

**EclipseLink24.ear**

- lib/eclipselink.jar
- META-INF/application.xml
- META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
- META-INF/weblogic-application.xml

***application.xml***

```
<application>
  <display-name>EclipseLink 2.4 Shared Library</display-name>
  <module>
    <java></java>
  </module>
</application>
```

***MANIFEST.MF***

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.8.2
Created-By: 1.7.0_04-b21 (Oracle Corporation)
Extension-Name: EclipseLink-2.4.0
Specification-Version: 2.4.0
Implementation-Version: 2.4.0.v20120608-r11652
```

***weblogic-application.xml***

```
<weblogic-application>
  <prefer-application-packages>
    <package-name>org.eclipse.persistence.*</package-name>
  </prefer-application-packages>
</weblogic-application>
```

**USE THE SHARED LIBRARY**

Once the shared library has been deployed, you need to configure your enterprise applications to use it.

**SampleApplication.ear**

- META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
- META-INF/weblogic-application.xml
- SampleApplication.war

***weblogic-application.xml***

The `weblogic-application.xml` file is used to reference the shared library.  The entries in the `library-ref` element need to match the corresponding entries from MANIFEST.MF in the shared library.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wls:weblogic-application xmlns:wls="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-application" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/javaee_5.xsd http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-application http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-application/1.2/weblogic-application.xsd">
    <!--weblogic-version:10.3.4-->
    <wls:application-param>
        <wls:param-name>webapp.encoding.default</wls:param-name>
        <wls:param-value>UTF-8</wls:param-value>
    </wls:application-param>
    <wls:library-ref>
        <wls:library-name>EclipseLink-2.4.0</wls:library-name>
        <wls:specification-version>2.4.0</wls:specification-version>
        <wls:implementation-version>2.4.0.v20120608-r11652</wls:implementation-version>
        <wls:exact-match>true</wls:exact-match>
    </wls:library-ref>
</wls:weblogic-application>
```

***TestServlet***

Below is a test servlet that you could include in the WAR to test the EclipseLink version.

```
package com.example;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class TestServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public TestServlet() {
        super();
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.append("<html><body>");
        out.append(org.eclipse.persistence.Version.getVersion());
        out.append("</body></html>");
    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    }

}
```

**For More Information**

- http://buttso.blogspot.com/2011/07/plugging-in-later-version-of.html

Comment: I am using 2.4.0 version of eclipselink. My testcase without any spring mvc depdency works fine for json output but it's not working in my webapp with spring mvc. do i need to take care of any other jar or it's version?

Comment: @Navin - Which version of WebLogic are you deploying to?  The WebLogic install includes EclipseLink, so the earlier version may be coming from there.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Blaise. I still need to try this. I will let you know if it works. So you mentioned to deploy weblogic-application.xml as part of .ear file. But i am deploying a web application (.war) so the entries you mentioned for weblogic-application.xml should be in weblogic.xml file for a web app?

Comment: @Navin - You will need to wrap the WAR in an EAR.  I wasn't able to get this work by specifying the shared library in the `weblogic.xml` file.

Comment: Thanks Blaise. I will wrap the war in an EAR.